# Different behavior of methods.include? between ruby 1.8.7 and ruby 1.9 & 2

Tags: ruby

test script:

```
class X
  def hello
    puts "hello"
  end
end

x = X.new
puts x.methods.include? :hello
puts x.methods.include? 'hello'
```

with ruby 1.8.7:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
$ ruby test.rb
false
true
```

with ruby 1.9.3 and ruby 2.1, 2.2:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]
$ ruby test.rb
true
false
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
$ ruby test.rb
true
false
```

1. Why does it differ between 1.8 and the newer versions? Any historical reason or is it a bug in 1.8 version?
2. Why do symbol and string make difference here? Why doesn't it work with both of the two styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking the difference between ruby 1.8 and 1.9 (and later), I found the reason is:

'instance_methods' has been changed from **array of strings** to **array of symbols**

A proper way of checking 'whether the method is defined' is:

```
x.respond_to?(:hello) # or string, both work
```